# Failed startup of context c.g.a.r.j.AppEngineWebAppContext due to FeatureNotEnabledException: app_identity_service.GetAccessToken

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

After adding Google Storage to a Google Endpoints app written in Java, the web instances seem not to be able to start up anymore, when deployed to GAE. However, all works fine when run locally (`mvn appengine:run`).

Exception from the logs:

Failed startup of context

```
c.g.a.r.j.AppEngineWebAppContext@442bff20{/,file:///workspace/,UNAVAILABLE}{/workspace}
com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$FeatureNotEnabledException: app_identity_service.GetAccessToken 
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1602)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl.doSyncCall(ApiProxyImpl.java:362)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl.lambda$makeSyncCall$0(ApiProxyImpl.java:284)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl.makeSyncCall(ApiProxyImpl.java:283)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl.makeSyncCall(ApiProxyImpl.java:81)
    at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.makeSyncCall(ApiProxy.java:120)
    at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.makeSyncCall(ApiProxy.java:81)
    at com.google.appengine.api.appidentity.AppIdentityServiceImpl.getAccessTokenUncached(AppIdentityServiceImpl.java:250)
    at com.google.appengine.api.appidentity.AppIdentityServiceImpl.getAccessToken(AppIdentityServiceImpl.java:327)
    at endpoints.repackaged.com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.appengine.auth.oauth2.AppIdentityCredential.intercept(AppIdentityCredential.java:98)
    at endpoints.repackaged.com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.appengine.auth.oauth2.AppIdentityCredential$AppEngineCredentialWrapper.intercept(AppIdentityCredential.java:243)
    at endpoints.repackaged.com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:868)
    at endpoints.repackaged.com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
    at endpoints.repackaged.com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
    at endpoints.repackaged.com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
    at endpoints.repackaged.com.google.api.config.ServiceConfigSupplier.fetchLatestServiceVersion(ServiceConfigSupplier.java:179)
    at endpoints.repackaged.com.google.api.config.ServiceConfigSupplier.fetch(ServiceConfigSupplier.java:146)
    at endpoints.repackaged.com.google.api.config.ServiceConfigSupplier.get(ServiceConfigSupplier.java:131)
    at endpoints.repackaged.com.google.api.config.ServiceConfigSupplier.get(ServiceConfigSupplier.java:50)
    at endpoints.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Suppliers$ExpiringMemoizingSupplier.get(Suppliers.java:241)
    at endpoints.repackaged.com.google.api.config.ServiceConfigFetcher.fetch(ServiceConfigFetcher.java:41)
    at com.google.api.control.ServiceManagementConfigFilter$1.load(ServiceManagementConfigFilter.java:33)
    at com.google.api.control.ConfigFilter.init(ConfigFilter.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.initialize(FilterHolder.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.lambda$initialize$0(ServletHandler.java:750)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:774)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:379)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1449)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty94.AppEngineWebAppContext.startWebapp(AppEngineWebAppContext.java:274)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1414)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:916)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:288)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:524)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty94.AppEngineWebAppContext.doStart(AppEngineWebAppContext.java:218)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty94.AppVersionHandlerFactory.doCreateHandler(AppVersionHandlerFactory.java:207)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty94.AppVersionHandlerFactory.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerFactory.java:125)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty94.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:82)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty94.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:176)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.RequestRunner.dispatchServletRequest(RequestRunner.java:264)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.RequestRunner.dispatchRequest(RequestRunner.java:229)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.RequestRunner.run(RequestRunner.java:194)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:273)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$FeatureNotEnabledException: app_identity_service.GetAccessToken 
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.runtime.ApiProxyUtils.convertApiError(ApiProxyUtils.java:81)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.runtime.ApiProxyUtils.getApiError(ApiProxyUtils.java:198)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$AsyncApiFuture.success(ApiProxyImpl.java:684)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$AsyncApiFuture.success(ApiProxyImpl.java:581)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.http.HttpApiHostClient.receivedResponse(HttpApiHostClient.java:296)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.http.JettyHttpApiHostClient$Listener.onComplete(JettyHttpApiHostClient.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.ResponseNotifier.notifyComplete(ResponseNotifier.java:218)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.ResponseNotifier.notifyComplete(ResponseNotifier.java:210)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpReceiver.terminateResponse(HttpReceiver.java:481)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpReceiver.terminateResponse(HttpReceiver.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpReceiver.responseSuccess(HttpReceiver.java:424)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpReceiverOverHTTP.messageComplete(HttpReceiverOverHTTP.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.handleContentMessage(HttpParser.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseContent(HttpParser.java:1722)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:1551)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpReceiverOverHTTP.parse(HttpReceiverOverHTTP.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpReceiverOverHTTP.process(HttpReceiverOverHTTP.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpReceiverOverHTTP.receive(HttpReceiverOverHTTP.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpChannelOverHTTP.receive(HttpChannelOverHTTP.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpConnectionOverHTTP.onFillable(HttpConnectionOverHTTP.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    ... 1 more
```

What is the reason for the following exception and how can it be fixed?

```
com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$FeatureNotEnabledException: app_identity_service.GetAccessToken
```

The app is built with maven has the following dependencies in `pom.xml`:

```
  <!-- See https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/bom -->
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>libraries-bom</artifactId>
        <version>25.4.0</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.endpoints</groupId>
      <artifactId>endpoints-management-control-appengine-all</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.14</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
      <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.luhuiguo</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspose-pdf</artifactId>
      <version>23.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
      <!-- <version>1.118.1</version> -->
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.endpoints</groupId>
      <artifactId>endpoints-framework</artifactId>
      <version>${endpoints.framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
```

Comment: If your application is trying to call an API which is not enabled for the Java 11 runtime,which means the app appears to still be on the Java 8 runtime which is not supported anymore it will receive a `com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$FeatureNotEnabledException error`.

Comment: Thanks @SathiAiswarya - I think you are definitely on to something, since I was forced to go from java8 to java11 first, then to java17.

So now the app is running under java17, which I can verify in the app engine's console under versions.

However I don't really understand where the conflict is and how I can resolve it. Can you try to elaborate a bit more what you suspect about the issue?

Comment: seems  App Engine API not enabled,  enable the API in deploy.yaml and check

Comment: Could you try setting the dependency version for google-cloud-storage to 2.19.0?

Comment: How are you instantiating your google.cloud.storage.Client() instance? Ensure that it maintains state by instantiating it whenever necessary or make it as a singleton so that it can create a state and be reusable whenever necessary,